# iOS-like Navigation Drawer for Android?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, navigation-drawer, slide

I'm looking for a way to reproduce the navigation drawer of iOS on Android.

I can't figured out how to reproduce it.

The Navigation Drawer on iOS slide all the previous page and keep a little part of it on screen like this:

[iOS like Navigation Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXDWy.gif)

Meanwhile the android Navigation Drawer goes over the previous page and hide it like this:

[Android like Navigation Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hdHZ.gif)

Is it just possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Affirmative, it's very much possible in Android. Add the following in your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'com.infideap.drawerbehavior:drawer-behavior:0.2.2'
}
```

Use `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` inside your layout with  `com.infideap.drawerbehavior.AdvanceDrawerLayout` to achieve this type of behavior like this:

```
<com.infideap.drawerbehavior.AdvanceDrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_default"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</com.infideap.drawerbehavior.AdvanceDrawerLayout>
```

For more on the implementations & sample demos, please follow this [link](https://github.com/shiburagi/Drawer-Behavior). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

iOS doesn't have a build-in Navigation Drawer component. The first link you provided contains a custom implementation. Best possible is to use third-party solution. For example, quite popular is [SideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu).

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there a way to do this in Android ? I can't find any third-party solution for Android